# Simpler method to redirect outgoing connection to localhost in Windows 10

Tags: windows, proxy, netsh

Ok, so I have a program that talks with a device through Bluetooth and enables it to open a socket connection to an external host. I have a simulator that runs in my computer and I want to redirect the outgoing connection to the simulator running in localhost. Even for Windows, this seems more complicated that I think it should be.

Based in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/712970/can-i-redirect-route-ip-adress-to-another-ip-address-windows) I tried `netsh int ip add addr 1 111.222.333.444/32 st=ac sk=tr`

Based on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/171850/redirect-request-to-an-external-ip-to-localhost-emulate-a-server) I tried `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=111.222.333.444 listenport=15000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=2405 protocol=tcp`

While the outgoing connection always goes to port 15000, I can control the port where my simulator is listening. It is 2405 merely because the first version of the simulator used that port for some reason.

I tried with both active and forgot about them while I searched for alternatives.

I then found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/862459/is-netsh-based-forwarding-to-127-0-0-1-possible-at-all) with no solution, but the OP said that he solved his problem with [PassPort](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/), which finally enabled the device's outgoing communication to reach my simulator.

When I tried to revert the netsh commands, I discovered out that I needed **both** commands active for PassPort to do its trick.

Isn't there a simpler method to achieve this? My system is Windows 10 21H1

I can't use the hosts file because the connection is made directly to the IP, not to a hostname.

Edit: apologies, I just realized that this might have been better to ask in superuser... can I move it or need to delete/recreate?

Comment: Wow.. this post solved my problem.. I was only redirecting IP and port using `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 `, but a loopback and skip-a-ssource using `netsh int ip` was also needed, and finally worked for me thanks..